# When is gaussian elimination not solvable without pivoting?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As in the topic,
how do I check if matrix for gaussian elimination is not solvable without using pivoting? In other words, how do I check when pivoting is necessary?

And also I have second question,while doing back substitution how do I check if there is no possible answer or there are infinite amount of them?

Cheers

Comment: There are no solutions when (after elimination has been done) you find an equation of the form $0=a$ with the constant term $a\neq0$. There are infinitely many solutions, when the last echelon has length larger than $1$ (and we are not in the case of no solutions).

Comment: You are forced to pivot when the next column in which to do elimination, has a zero in the row of the same index. Nevertheless, even if this entry is non-zero it might be worth it to pivot to another row if the computations are simpler, or (when done on a computer) more numerically stable (less numerical error will occur). For example, if you find a row further down with coefficient $1$, it is nice to use it, because you won't have to do divisions.

Comment: For square matrices, you can always check if the determinant is not zero to see if it is solvable. Of course, calculating the determinant is a major pain for large matrices. Fortunately, you can use Gaussian elimination to make the matrix upper triangular, then multiply the diagonal elements to get the determinant - much easier than the formula.... Finding the rank of the matrix is easier than the determinant and also solves the problem. You find the rank by ... Gaussian elimination! The point is: Gaussian elimination *is the easy method*. The world is as it is, not as we would have it.